# How to return 0 value rows with count

Tags: sqlite

I have 2 tables , and I'm supposed to return number of red boats reserved each day

I got it to retun only values with non 0, and I can't figure out how to include the 0

my query

```
select r.day, count(distinct r.bname)
from reservation r, boat b
where r.bname = b.bname and color = 'red'
group by day
```

This query prints out all rows with non zero values returned

How do I include the zero values?

I have tried using a left join and no luck... or maybe im doing this wrong

```
  Table    Attributes

  sailor| sname   rating
           Brutus  1
           Andy    8
           Horatio 7
           Rusty   8
           Bob     1

  boat|bname        color   rating
       SpeedQueen   white    9
       Interlake    red      8
       Marine       blue     7
       Bay          red      3

  reservation| sname bname     day
               Andy  Interlake Monday
               Andy  Bay       Wednesday
               Andy  Marine    Saturday
               Rusty Bay       Sunday
               Rusty Interlake Wednesday
               Rusty Marine    Wednesday
               Bob   Bay       Monday


  alldays|     day
              monday
              tuesday
              wednesday
              thursday
              friday
              saturday
              sunday
```

My query prints out

```
 Monday 2
 Wednesday 2
 Sunday 1
```

when i need it to do it like this

```
 Monday 2
 Tuesday 0
 Wednesday 2
 Thursday 0
 Friday 0
 Saturday 0
 Sunday 1
```

I understand since sqlite3 doesnt return null values, i need to do a  join to get those values? but i tried its not working

Comment: Sample tables please

Comment: The only way to get zero counts is to use an OUTER join against a list of the distinct values you want to see zero counts for.

Comment: Where should the other day values come from? Do you really want to get the number of reservations for August 2, 1492? If not, which days do you want?

Comment: updated, see above for info

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.day, count(distinct b.bname) 
FROM reservation b, boat a 
WHERE b.bname = a.bname and a.color = 'red' 
GROUP BY b.day UNION ALL 
SELECT c.day, 0 
FROM alldays c 
WHERE c.day NOT IN(SELECT b.day FROM reservation b, boat a WHERE b.bname = a.bname AND a.color = 'red');
```